# Rails semantic logger tags stopped working after upgrade to 4.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

**Before upgrade**
I used rails_semantic_logger with tags for logging request id, and session id. I had in my logging initialzier and it worked adding tags with these ids:

```
  config.log_tags = [
      #:host,
      #:remote_ip,
      lambda { |request| "#{request.uuid}"[0..32] },
      lambda { |request| "#{request.cookie_jar["_session_id"]}" },
  ]
```

Sample log row:

```
2019-04-07 13:54:03.563661 I [25929:puma 001] [["a2eb2610-9db1-475b-8d0a-547dc514d", "7713d31653d81aa6d9fe1882c282cc95"]] (499.8ms) DebugController -- Completed #show -- { :controller => "DebugController", :action => "show", :format => "*/*", :method => "GET", :path => "/debug", :status => 200, :view_runtime => 463.81, :rendered_format => :js, :variant => [], :db_runtime => 32.32, :status_message => "OK" }
```

Environment:

- rails 5.0.4
- ruby 2.4.2
- semantic_logger 4.2.0
- rails_semantic_loggger 4.1.3

**After upgrade**
Recently I upgraded my enviroment to newer versions of rails and gems (specific versions below) I can't setup automatic tags logging. I tried some combinations with named_tags like this:

```
  config.log_tags = {
      host:       :host,
      ip:         :remote_ip,
      request_id: :request_id,
      session_id: -> request { request.cookie_jar['_session_id'] }
  }
```

But it simply doesn't work:

```
2019-04-07 14:19:04.131479 I [23455:puma 001] (394.2ms) DebugController -- Completed #show -- { :controller => "DebugController", :action => "show", :format => "*/*", :method => "GET", :path => "/debug", :status => 200, :view_runtime => 384.13, :db_runtime => 6.99, :status_message => "OK" }
```

Environment:
- rails 5.1.7
- ruby 2.4.2
- semantic_logger 4.2.0
- rails_semantic_loggger 4.4.1

I created a sample app to picture the problem: https://github.com/camaeel/logger-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic logger from version 4.3 or 4.4 needs setting config.log_tags earlier. It need to be set in config/[ENV_NAME].rb or application.rb. Initializer in config/initializers/*.rb is too late as loggers for Rails & Rack are initialzied before.